# Sum not being stored correctly

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cuda

This is my second try at a CUDA program and parallel development.

I'm trying to find why the dot product two arrays.

Example:

Given

```
A = [1 2 3] 
B = [4 5 6]

C[0] = (1)(4) + (1)(5) + (1)(6)  
C[1] = (2)(4) + (2)(5) + (2)(6)  
C[2] = (3)(4) + (3)(5) + (3)(6)
```

I intialize 2 arrays, A and B , randomly fill the elements within a range, then I multiply each element in `A` with each in `B` and store the sum of the products in a third array identified as `C`. I've set the array's size of A, B and C to 100.

That gives me 10'000 multiplications which are the ones that I parallelise by using 100 blocks and 128 threads (due to warp size).

Here is my kernel function:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *a, float *b, float *c, const int N) {
    if( threadIdx.x < N ) 
        c[blockIdx.x] += a[blockIdx.x] * b[threadIdx.x];
}
```

This is my reasoning, since the aggregation has to be accumulated in `C` which has the same index as the pivot index in `A` so I can reuse the `blockidx.x` and that 'should' work correctly; but it doesn't.

My suspicion is that the `C` index gets cleared or is not shared when the thread changes but I'm really not sure which is why I seek advice.

Here's is the complete code, I've explicitly avoided the `HANDLE_ERROR` function wrappers for shortness

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <time.h>

#define M 100

__global__ void kernel(float *a, float *b, float *c, const int N) {
    if(threadIdx.x < N) 
        c[blockIdx.x] += a[blockIdx.x] * b[threadIdx.x];
}

void init_array(float*, const int);
void fill_array(float*, const int, const float); 
void print_array(float*, const int, *char);

int main (void) {
    srand( time(NULL) );

    float a[M], b[M], c[M] = { 0.0 };
    float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    const int S = sizeof(float) * M;

    init_array(a, M);
    init_array(b, M);

    print_array(a, M, "a");
    print_array(b, M, "b");
    print_array(c, M, "c");

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, S);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, S);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, S);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<M, M + 28>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, M);

    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, S, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    print_array(c, M, "c");

    return 0;
}

void init_array(float *a, const int N) {
   int i;  
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
       a[i] = rand() % M + 1;
}

void fill_array(float *a, const int N, const float v) {
   int i;  
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
       a[i] = v;
}

void print_array(float *a, const int N, char *d) {
   int i;  
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
       printf("\n%s[%d]: %f",d, i, a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you expect in the result? for example, if a=[1 2 3] and b=[4 5 6] and c=[0 0 0] what should be the final c.

Comment: Well, if we fill `A` and `B` with 3.0 we should get `3 * 3 * 100 = 900`, 900 in each element of `C`.

Comment: Now, in response to your comment, given `A=[1 2 3]` and `B=[4 5 6]`, we would have `(1)(4) + (1)(5) + (1)(6) = 15`.

Comment: OK. Notice that you are writing to same location of global memory by concurrent threads of a block. You should use atomic operations to get the correct answer. I will try to provide the code soon.

Answer (score 1):

When accumulating the result into C you have a mutual exclusion. You cannot have multiple threads update the same array index. One way to fix it is to use atomic instructions, in your case atomicAdd(..).

The reason to why this does not work is that thread 0 and 1 in block 0 update the same position in C array. You get a race condition.

Comment: How would it be fixed without atomic instructions, using shared memory?

Comment: Yes you could use shared memory but you will have the same problem there. On the other hand the atomic operation on shared memory is faster than on global memory.

Comment: Thinking on the race condition you mention, why would it matter which thread updated the index?, as the index is just the accumulator, from my point of view it doesn't matter which thread updated the index first what ever value was there will just be added to the product.

Comment: @brano: you could use shared memory to perform a reduction within the block, and then have one thread in each block do an atomicAdd to global memory. That way you avoid atomics on shared memory and reduce the number of atomics on global by a couple of orders of magnitude. Also note that atomic operations on global memory are much faster on Kepler GPUs than on older GPUs.

Comment: @Triztian: From your point of view yes :D But you are writing code in cuda C. If you look at the instructions executed to perform the accumulation you will realize that threads can interleave in between and produce incorrect result.

Comment: @Tom: Agree. I was just anwering him in the sense that he can not reuse use the same kernel and just swap global to shared memory. You are correct that there are other ways to rewrite the code and get better performance.

Comment: @brano: Absolutely, your answer was good (+1) in terms of the actual problem, but I also think it's worth mentioning that there are better ways of solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot simpler to use cuBLAS: the `cublasSdot()` routine does what you are looking for (i.e. dot product two vectors).

That doesn't help you learn how to write parallel code or work in CUDA, but it will give you good performance and will be optimised for different GPUs. Best practice is to use a library whenever possible, unless there is a good reason not to.

Another answer has pointed out that you need to use atomics or some other method to avoid the race. A more efficient way would be to have each thread compute a partial result, do a block-wise reduction (see the SDK for examples of this), and finally have one thread in each block do an atomic addition in the global memory to accumulate the results from different blocks.

Answer (score -2):

Your code writes multiple values to the same location in global memory with no synchronization and consideration. You can fix it using some kind of critical section. Here is the code doing what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <time.h>

#define M 5

__global__ void kernel(float *a, float *b, float *c, const int N) {
    __shared__ int lock;
    lock=0u;
    if(threadIdx.x < N) {
        __syncthreads();
        float mult = a[blockIdx.x] * b[threadIdx.x];

        int leaveLoop = 0;
        while (leaveLoop==0) {
            if (atomicExch(&lock, 1u) == 0u) {
                //critical section
                c[blockIdx.x] += mult;
                leaveLoop = 1;
                atomicExch(&lock,0u);
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
}

void init_array(float *a, const int N) {
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % M + 1;
}

void fill_array(float *a, const int N, const float v) {
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        a[i] = v;
}

void print_array(float *a, const int N, char *d) {
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("\n%s[%d]: %f",d, i, a[i]);
}

int main (void) {
    srand( time(NULL) );

    float a[M], b[M], c[M] = { 0.0 };
    float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    const int S = sizeof(float) * M;

    init_array(a, M);
    init_array(b, M);

    print_array(a, M, "a");
    print_array(b, M, "b");
    print_array(c, M, "c");

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, S);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, S);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, S);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, S, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<M, M + 28>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, M);

    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, S, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    print_array(c, M, "c");

    return 0;
}
```

To achieve your goal in aggregating the sum of multiply of array, I suggest you to use what proposed by @Tom if possible. I write this code because sometime it is easier to use your code instead of external library.

Comment: This is a really bad way of doing a reduction -- you are going to serialize on your lock when you shouldn't need any serialization for a parallel reduction.

Comment: @harrism: I tried to solve the issue 'Sum not being stored correctly' and of course the code is far from optimizations.